# Opening ArcGIS online data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, download, pitem

I am hoping to open the following polygon layer in QGIS:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=764b72f3f6754e8fb1360c95bdf18918

The download is a 'pitem' file.

Are these files exclusively for ArcGIS, or is it possible to open in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the right, in the webpage you have provided, there is a `URL` section. You can click on it (the `view` button), which leads to `https://services7.arcgis.com/XKcQKuJiT8ywGgE6/arcgis/rest/services/SDG3_3_2_NUTS3/FeatureServer`

This URL can be added in QGIS. Go to the menu `layer / add layer / add ArcGIS Feature Server layer`, then create a `new` connection and paste the URL.

Comment: As per above - do note though that with ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS Portals that are being published internally by organisations - may have security settings applied, which require a bit more complexity when it comes to connection parameters.