# Downloading pitem file from ArcGIS Online as shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, feature-service, pitem

I'm wanting to export the data connected to a "pitem" file (an ArgGIS "portal item" file).

Here in ArcGIS Online, you can click on "Open in ArcGIS Desktop", and it downloads the pitem file. I'm able to upload it into ArcGIS. I want to export the data as a shapefile.

Data:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d0559466f6994dd4b8e79298018b2fb8

I'd really like to do this in QGIS.  Currently, I'm having to download ArcGIS just to obtain this data.

I found instructions on how to open it in QGIS at [How to open ArcGIS online data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373327), but when I went to **Layer > Add Layer > Add ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer** and copied and pasted the URL given on the bottom of the right side of the page, and clicked "connect", it said "The query returned no layers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive just tested the link to the data above in QGIS, so it does work.

The URL is:

> https://services9.arcgis.com/IkktFdUAcY3WrH25/arcgis/rest/services/Global_Species_Richness_Patterns_for_Fishes/FeatureServer

try clicking that URL in your browser. What happens? Do you get the ArcGIS REST Services Directory page? If not, it might be your organisation is blocking those sites.

Alternatively, try opening the URL a different way in QGIS. Go to the Browser Panel (Right click on toolbar and select Browser panel if its not open). Navigate to ArcGIS Feature Service and right click > New Connection. Give it a name and paste that URL into the URL section.

Then expand the tree item in the browser until you see 'Global_Richness_Rarity_Fishes' and right click on that, and select 'Add Layer to Project'

The above steps are exactly what I did in QGIS - im using QGIS 3.14.1 Pi

To export, simply right-click the layer and export, choose your file type (eg shapefile), like you would any layer.

Comment: Thank you so much @nr_aus. I thought I did exactly that, I don't know why it didn't work. To add the final step: then export, simply right-click the layer and export, choose your file type (eg shapefile), like you would any layer.

Feel free to remove my name in the edit above, or put it in your own words.